# Dont see groovy installation option in my jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

[image]

Dont see Groovy home and path to groovy installation in my jenkins. Jenkins version is 2.77.
Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins 2.x all the tool configurations (Groovy,Maven, Ant, Gradle and even the JDK) under the "Global Tools" entry in Jenkins administration (Manage Jenkins).